# Range versus term boosting in Elastic Search

Tags: full-text-search, elasticsearch

I am struggling to make boosting work the way I want it to in Elastic Search.

Let's say I have some profiles indexed containing gender, interests and age, and let's say that I find it most relevant that the gender matches, then the interest and the least important criterium is the user's age. I was expecting the below query to result in an ordering of the matching profiles according to the just mentioned principle, but when I execute it I get some males first and then I get the female Anna of the age 50 before the female Maria who likes cars... why doesn't Maria get a higher score than Anna??

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                { "term"  : { "gender" : { "term": "male", "boost": 10.0 } } },
                { "term"  : { "likes"  : { "term": "cars", "boost" : 5.0 } } },
                { "range" : { "age"    : { "from" : 50,    "boost" : 1.0 } } }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
        }
    }    
}
```

Hints will be greatly appreciated,

Stine

---

These are the curl commands executed:

```
$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/profile/1 -d '{
    "nickname" : "bob",
    "gender" : "male",
    "age" : 48,
    "likes" : "airplanes"
}'

$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/profile/2 -d '{
    "nickname" : "carlos",
    "gender" : "male",
    "age" : 24,
    "likes" : "food"
}'

$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/profile/3 -d '{
    "nickname" : "julio",
    "gender" : "male",
    "age" : 18,
    "likes" : "ladies"
}'

$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/profile/4 -d '{
    "nickname" : "maria",
    "gender" : "female",
    "age" : 25,
    "likes" : "cars"
}'

$ curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/users/profile/5 -d '{
    "nickname" : "anna",
    "gender" : "female",
    "age" : 50,
    "likes" : "clothes"
}'

$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/users/profile/_search -d '{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "should" : [
                { "term" : { "gender" : { "term": "male", "boost": 10.0 } } },
                { "term" : { "likes" : { "term": "cars", "boost" : 5.0 } } },
                { "range" : { "age" : { "from" : 50, "boost" : 1.0 } } }
            ],
            "minimum_number_should_match" : 1
        }
    }    
}'
```

Comment: The tag `boost` is for the boost c++ library. Can you edit the tag out.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `boost` value is not absolute - it is [combined with other factors](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/scoring.html) to determine the relevance of each term.

You have two "genders" (I would assume) but many different "likes". So `male` is considered almost irrelevant, because it occurs so frequently within your data.  However, `cars` may only occur a few times, and thus is considered to be much more relevant.

This logic is useful for full text search, but not for enums, which are intended to be used essentially as filters.

Fortunately, you can disable this functionality on a per-field basis using `omit_term_freq_and_positions` and `omit_norms`.

Try setting your mapping as follows:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/test/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "test" : {
         "properties" : {
            "likes" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "omit_term_freq_and_positions" : 1,
               "omit_norms" : 1,
               "type" : "string"
            },
            "gender" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "omit_term_freq_and_positions" : 1,
               "omit_norms" : 1,
               "type" : "string"
            },
            "age" : {
               "type" : "integer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

**UPDATE**: Full working example:

Delete the existing index:

```
curl -XDELETE 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/?pretty=1'
```

Create the index with the new mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "profile" : {
         "properties" : {
            "likes" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "omit_term_freq_and_positions" : 1,
               "type" : "string",
               "omit_norms" : 1
            },
            "age" : {
               "type" : "integer"
            },
            "gender" : {
               "index" : "not_analyzed",
               "omit_term_freq_and_positions" : 1,
               "type" : "string",
               "omit_norms" : 1
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Index the test docs:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/profile/_bulk?pretty=1'  -d '
{"index" : {"_id" : 1}}
{"nickname" : "bob", "likes" : "airplanes", "age" : 48, "gender" : "male"}
{"index" : {"_id" : 2}}
{"nickname" : "carlos", "likes" : "food", "age" : 24, "gender" : "male"}
{"index" : {"_id" : 3}}
{"nickname" : "julio", "likes" : "ladies", "age" : 18, "gender" : "male"}
{"index" : {"_id" : 4}}
{"nickname" : "maria", "likes" : "cars", "age" : 25, "gender" : "female"}
{"index" : {"_id" : 5}}
{"nickname" : "anna", "likes" : "clothes", "age" : 50, "gender" : "female"}
'
```

Refresh the index (to be sure that the latest docs are visible to search):

```
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/_refresh?pretty=1'
```

Search:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/users/profile/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "bool" : {
         "minimum_number_should_match" : 1,
         "should" : [
            {
               "term" : {
                  "gender" : {
                     "boost" : 10,
                     "term" : "male"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "term" : {
                  "likes" : {
                     "boost" : 5,
                     "term" : "cars"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "range" : {
                  "age" : {
                     "boost" : 1,
                     "from" : 50
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
'
```

Results:

```
# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "bob",
#                "likes" : "airplanes",
#                "age" : 48,
#                "gender" : "male"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.053500723,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "1",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "carlos",
#                "likes" : "food",
#                "age" : 24,
#                "gender" : "male"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.053500723,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "2",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "julio",
#                "likes" : "ladies",
#                "age" : 18,
#                "gender" : "male"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.053500723,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "3",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "anna",
#                "likes" : "clothes",
#                "age" : 50,
#                "gender" : "female"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.029695695,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "5",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "maria",
#                "likes" : "cars",
#                "age" : 25,
#                "gender" : "female"
#             },
#             "_score" : 0.015511602,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "4",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 0.053500723,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 5,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "took" : 4
# }
```

**UPDATE: Alternative approach**

Here, I present an alternative query which, while more verbose, gives you a much more predictable result.  It involves using the [custom filters score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/custom-filters-score-query.html). First, we filter the docs down to docs that match at least one of the conditions.  Because we use the [constant score](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/constant-score-query.html) query, all docs have an initial score of 1.

The custom filters score allows us to boost each doc if it matches a filter:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_all/_search?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "query" : {
      "custom_filters_score" : {
         "query" : {
            "constant_score" : {
               "filter" : {
                  "or" : [
                     {
                        "term" : {
                           "gender" : "male"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "term" : {
                           "likes" : "cars"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "range" : {
                           "age" : {
                              "gte" : 50
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         },
         "score_mode" : "total",
         "filters" : [
            {
               "boost" : "10",
               "filter" : {
                  "term" : {
                     "gender" : "male"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "boost" : "5",
               "filter" : {
                  "term" : {
                     "likes" : "cars"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "boost" : "1",
               "filter" : {
                  "range" : {
                     "age" : {
                        "gte" : 50
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
'
```

You will see that the scores associated with each doc are nice round numbers, which are easily traced back to the matched clauses:

```
# [Fri Jun  8 21:30:24 2012] Response:
# {
#    "hits" : {
#       "hits" : [
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "bob",
#                "likes" : "airplanes",
#                "age" : 48,
#                "gender" : "male"
#             },
#             "_score" : 10,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "1",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "carlos",
#                "likes" : "food",
#                "age" : 24,
#                "gender" : "male"
#             },
#             "_score" : 10,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "2",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "julio",
#                "likes" : "ladies",
#                "age" : 18,
#                "gender" : "male"
#             },
#             "_score" : 10,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "3",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "maria",
#                "likes" : "cars",
#                "age" : 25,
#                "gender" : "female"
#             },
#             "_score" : 5,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "4",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          },
#          {
#             "_source" : {
#                "nickname" : "anna",
#                "likes" : "clothes",
#                "age" : 50,
#                "gender" : "female"
#             },
#             "_score" : 1,
#             "_index" : "users",
#             "_id" : "5",
#             "_type" : "profile"
#          }
#       ],
#       "max_score" : 10,
#       "total" : 5
#    },
#    "timed_out" : false,
#    "_shards" : {
#       "failed" : 0,
#       "successful" : 20,
#       "total" : 20
#    },
#    "took" : 6
# }
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, thank you :) Clearly there is a lot left for me to understand, e.g. mapping! I tried to set the mapping you suggest which resulted in my query not including Anna at all in the result??

Comment: You must have done something wrong. I've added a full working example above which demonstrates that it works. As far as learning about mapping, have a look at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/

Comment: Given that 'anna' was the last record you added, it may not have been visible to search by the time you ran your query, eg if you ran all the commands in a script.  The index is refreshed automatically every second.  I've included a forced refresh in the example to make sure that it is visible.

Comment: But in your result Anna is still listed before Maria even though cars should be better than matching the age criterium?

Comment: Hmm, still not getting Anna listed in my result even after starting all over and including the refresh command.

Comment: Re: not getting Anna: What version of ES are you using? How do your curl statements differ from mine?

Comment: As far as ordering goes, scoring is a complex beast.  You can try running the query with `explain=1` in the query string.  It outputs a LOT of debugging which is quite hard to read, but it gives you more of an idea of how the score is derived.  It turns out that the range query counts for more than it should, so try changing to boost for the range query to 0.5.

Comment: 0.19.4. But apparently I left out profiles in my query url. When I add that I do actually get Anna out. The order is still not reflecting that I value car lickers over people above 50 years old?

Comment: See my previous comment about range and boost 0.5

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12309/discussion-between-drtech-and-stine)